# Show that if $R$ is reflexive, then $S$ is a subset of $R$ composition $S$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

I know how to show that a specific relation is reflexive, but I have problems with more abstract though still basic examples.

Let $R$, $S$ be binary relations on the $X \neq \emptyset$.

Show that:

$R$ is reflexive $\implies$ $S \subset R \circ S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, showing that $S \subseteq R \circ S$ amounts to show that if $(x, y) \in S$ then $(x,y) \in R \circ S$.

How can we show it, under the hypothesis that $R$ is reflexive?

Let $(x,y ) \in S$. As $R$ is reflexive, $(x,x) \in R$. By definition of composition, from $(x,x) \in R$ and $(x,y ) \in S$ it follows that $(x,y) \in R \circ S$.
Since we are talking about a *generic* $(x,y ) \in S$, we have showed that $S \subseteq R \circ S$.

---

The crucial point in the proof above is the definition of *composition* for relations: $(x,y) \in R \circ S$ means that there exists $z \in X$ such that $(x,z) \in R$ and $(z,y) \in S$.

In the case above, since $R$ is reflexive, it is easy to find the "intermediate term" $z$ for the composition: just take $x$.